# No such file when it exists

Tags: linux, shell, alpine-linux

How is this possible?

```
bash: /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs: No such file or directory
bash-4.3# cd /usr/local/phantomjs/bin
bash-4.3# ls
phantomjs
bash-4.3#
```

The content of `/usr/local/phantomjs/bin` is the `phantomjs` file but when I try to execute it, it looks like it does not exist.

FYI, I'm on Alpine linux 3.3

Update1

```
bash-4.3# ls -lF /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      67932064 Jan 25  2016 /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs*
bash-4.3# lf -lF /usr/local/phantomjs/bin
bash: lf: command not found
bash-4.3# ls -lF /usr/local/phantomjs/bin
total 66340
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      67932064 Jan 25  2016 phantomjs*
```

Update2

```
bash-4.3# file /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
bash: file: command not found
bash-4.3# head -n1 /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
ELF>xvA@`�
Q�t/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU����!�`�L`�L^|��������h�TT@T@DD`��`�L`�P�tddB�dB�dB��g
```

Update3

```
bash-4.3# echo $PATH
/usr/local/phantomjs/bin:/usr/local/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
bash-4.3# ruby -v
ruby 2.1.10p492 (2016-04-01 revision 54464) [x86_64-linux]
```

Update4

```
bash-4.3# strace /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
execve("/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs", ["/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantom"...], [/* 13 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
writev(2, [{"strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 39}, {"\n", 1}], 2strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
writev(2, [{"", 0}, {NULL, 0}], 2)      = 0
getpid()                                = 12
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Thanks

Comment: Let's see the output of `ls -lF /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs` as well as `lf -lF /usr/local/phantomjs/bin`. Please [edit].

Comment: Oops. Yes, I really did mean `ls -lF`. Sorry for the confusion! Can we also see the output of `file /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs` please, and if that says anything like "text" or "script", also `head -n1 /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`. I have a hypothesis, and that would potentially confirm or falsify it (or at the very least point us in the right direction).

Comment: Okay, not what I expected, but helpful. Since you have `ls` but not `file` immediately available, I now suspect that your `$PATH` is not fully populated. Let's see `echo $PATH` to confirm that; I suspect it will include `/bin` but not `/usr/bin`, for starters. It's also possible that other parts of your environment (such as `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) are incomplete for the same reason that causes `$PATH` to be incomplete, but `$PATH` is easy to verify at a glance. Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux, Alpine's minimalism might be a factor here.

Comment: see Update3. FYI `ruby` works as expected. The issue is only with `phantomjs`.

Comment: Okay, this is actually odd. Hopefully someone will be able to take the details thus found and actually describe the behavior seen, because I am running out of ideas to try at the moment.

Comment: It is compiled Python and is purportedly self-contained, but "relies on Fontconfig (the package fontconfig or libfontconfig, depending on the distribution." A clue? no idea! http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: Please provide the output of `uname -m` and `file /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`. I know this confusing behavior, when you try to run a binary compiled for a different cpu architecture than that of the current machine. How did you installed / obtained the `phantomjs` binary?

Comment: Ok, I've seen right now, you don't have `file` installed, but the headline identifies the binary as a x86_64 executable already.

Comment: If you are getting this from running a Go program please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729748/installed-go-binary-not-found-in-path-on-alpine-linux-docker

Answer (score 7):

The shell will report an ambiguous "*No such file or directory*" for an executable when the shell cannot find a dependency for that executable.
The missing dependency is typically a required shared library or a dynamic loader.

Use the **strace** command to explicitly view the **open()** syscall that fails during the execution request (e.g. `strace /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`).

**Addendum**

> ```
> execve("/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs", ["/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantom"...], [/* 13 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> ```

The evecve syscall returned the error code ENOENT, which the man page describes as "the file *filename* or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found."

Usually I've seen strace provide better resolution of the missing file.
The next step is to examine the executable file for its dependencies.
Use the **strings** command to extract the dynamic linker/loader, shared libraries, and entry-points listed at the beginning of the executable file.

```
strings /usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs | less
```

For each *filename* that you can identity in this list, you then have to verify that the file is installed in your root filesystem.

```
$ file modetest
modetest: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.10.0, stripped

$ strings modetest | less
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3    <=
libdrm.so.2    <=
drmModeFreeObjectProperties
drmModeFreePlaneResources
_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
 ...
libpthread.so.0    <=
pthread_join
pthread_create
__errno_location
 ...
libc.so.6    <=
strcpy
exit
mmap64
 ...
```

From your previous Update2, the first file would be **/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2**.

---

Comment: @macsig --  See addendum.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have solved the issue by installing an Alpine specific PhantomJS version (found after googling for a while) instead of from the "standard" version.

Comment: For some reasons It doesn't work on alpine.  I used this command / repo : `curl -Lo phantom.tgz https://github.com/DarthHater/docker-phantomjs2/releases/download/2.1.1/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz | tar xf -C /` then you can use `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`