# Systemd fails to locate executable although it exists

Tags: services, systemd

I am on Arch Linux and have this service named `toto.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` that I want to run:

```
[Unit]
Description=Toto
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/toto.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Where `toto.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo toto
```

And when I start it, it fails with the following error as follows:

```
Jun 13 00:11:15 scx systemd[1]: Started Toto.
Jun 13 00:11:15 scx (test.sh)[14097]: toto.service: Failed to locate executable /opt/toto/toto.sh: No such file or directory
Jun 13 00:11:15 scx (test.sh)[14097]: spark.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/toto/toto.sh: No such file or directory
Jun 13 00:11:15 scx systemd[1]: toto.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 13 00:11:15 scx systemd[1]: toto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why doesn’t it find `/opt/toto/toto.sh`?

Comment: you didn't indicate if the file was marked as executable and if the user the service is supposed to run under has access to it. My guess is the latter being that the user the service is spawned under can't see the file.  Try logging in as that user (a simple passwd hack) and see if you can see said file when logging in as that user.

Comment: On second thought.. after looking at your service file, you don't even specify what user you want this to run as.  Have you considered that?

Comment: Study https://superuser.com/questions/1176200/no-such-file-when-it-exists/1176328#1176328

Comment: There is something fishy here. In the file there is `ExecStart=/opt/toto.sh`, but the error message mentions `/opt/toto/toto.sh` which is obviously a different pathname. Additionally we're dealing with `toto.service` and `spark.service` (huh?), and somehow `test.sh` is involved in this. *Maybe* your real setup is somewhat complicated and *maybe* instead of creating and testing an [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659), you got the code and errors from the non-minimal problem and (*maybe* inaptly) modified the snippets while posting, so it kinda looks minimal. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it permission errors on calling the script, but the workaround which worked for me is to call bash first:

```
ExecStart=bash /opt/toto.sh
```